# Count number of arguments passed to function

Tags: r, function, ellipsis

I'm interested in counting a number of arguments passed to a function.  `length` can't be used for that purpose:

```
>> length(2,2,2,2,2)
Error in length(2, 2, 2, 2, 2) : 
  5 arguments passed to 'length' which requires 1
```

This is obvious as `length` takes 1 argument so:

```
length(c(2,2,2,2,2))
```

would produce the desired result - 5.

## Solution

I want to call my function like that **`myFunction(arg1, arg2, arg3)`.** This can be done with use of an ellipsis:

```
myCount <- function(...) {length(list(...))}
```

`myCount` would produce the desired result:

```
>> myCount(2,2,2,2,2)
[1] 5
```

## Problem

This is awfully inefficient. I'm calling this function on substantial number of arguments and creating lists just to count number of objects is wasteful. What's the better way of returning the number of arguments passed to a function?

Comment: @Gregor Fair point, I deleted the first bit.

Comment: 'calling with substatnial number of arguments' sounds like you're doing something weird. Function arguments are for programmers, machines should get lists too long for humans to read in a - for example - `list` :)

Comment: @liborm In a wider scheme of things I agree. In this particular case I was interested in this solution as it saves me changing the longer workflow when i cal functions by `get("sum")(arg, arg)`. From educational perspective I also wanted to see how this could be done in an efficient manner.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about

```
myCount <- function(...) {length(match.call())-1}
```

This just inspects the passed call (and removes 1 for the function name itself)

Comment: Perfect, this is what I was looking for.

Comment: Is it possible to count the number of arguments *inside* the function as well?

Answer (score 4):

**nargs** returns the number of arguments supplied to that function

```
myCount <- function(...) {
  nargs()
}

> myCount(2,2,2,2,2)
[1] 5
```

Reference https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/nargs.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is a somewhat elegant way using `length()` with `purrr::lift_*()` familiy functions.

Generally you are passing multiple arguments to `length()`, which is not working because `length()` takes a vector or a list as input.

So what we need is to convert the input from a vector/list to `...` (dots). `purrr::lift_*()` family provides a series of functions that do so.

One option can be converting from vector to dots:

```
> lift_vd(length)(2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
[1] 5
```

Another option can be converting from list to dots:

```
> lift_ld(length)(2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
[1] 5
```

Both options are working perfectly well, and what you need is using one of the `purrr::lift_*()` functions on `length()` before passing spliced arguments to it.