# Count expected arguments to be passed to a function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8

### The Problem

I 'need' to count the number of arguments expected to be passed to a function object. My commands are stored via their object, so I can reference each one individually. I already tried [inspect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) and while it seems perfect, it for some reason cannot distinguish between 0 arguments and 1 argument as both output 1. It seems I will have to link the actual code as it must be an error with my personal script. Here is the code:

```
# ============== Impots ==============
from shlex import split
from inspect import getfullargspec

# ==============  Main  ==============
class Command:
  def __init__(self, fn, name=None, aliases=None):
    self.name = name or fn.__name__
    self.aliases = aliases or []
    self.fn = fn

  def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return self.fn(*args, **kwargs)

  @property
  def all_names(self):
    return (self.name, *self.aliases)


# ============= Storage =============
class Commands(dict):
  def __init__(self, not_found: str='{} was not recognized.', argmismatch: str='{} takes {} arguments but {} were given.'):
    self.flag = [not_found, argmismatch]
    super().__init__()

  def _add_command(self, command):
    for cmd_name in command.all_names:
      if cmd_name in self:
        raise ValueError(f'Name or alias assigned to function {command.fn.__name__} is duplicate: {cmd_name}')
      self[cmd_name] = command

  def add_command(self, name=None, aliases=None):
    def inner_fn(fn):
      self._add_command(Command(fn, name, aliases))
      return fn
    return inner_fn

  def execute(self, user_input):
    self.command, *args = self.parse(user_input or 'no_input')
    if self.command.lower() in self:
      # THIS IS WHERE THE ISSUE HAPPENS
      print(f'Passed: {len(args)}')
      print(f'Expected: {len(getfullargspec(self[self.command])[0])}')
      if not (len(args)==len(getfullargspec(self[self.command])[0])):
        return (False, self.flag[1].format(self.command, len(getfullargspec(self[self.command])[0]), len(args)))
      self[self.command](*args)
      return (True, 'Command found!')
    else:
      return (False, self.flag[0].format(self.command))

  @staticmethod
  def parse(string):
    if (string=='no_input'):
      return ['','']
    return split(string)




cmd = Commands()
@cmd.add_command(name='foo')
def foo():
  print('bar')
cmd.execute('foo bar')
```

### Not the Problem

- I have already tried seeing if the list was filled with a `Null` value, it is not.
- It does this across platforms (VSCode, Repl.it, PyDroid) so it is not a weird os issue.
- I'm not sure if it could be `len()` treating it weirdly, but I know a normal empty list such as `[]` is counted as one.

---

I'm using this for the error message and possibly for auto-tips on what might have been wrong with the command, I would love any help and will update my post with new info and possible, correct, and incorrect solutions.

---

### Similar Posts

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44011918/count-number-of-arguments-passed-to-function) is similar in question but the solution provided does not match what I require.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `getfullargspec` if you only access the zeroth element.

`my_funct.__code__.co_argcount`